# Definition of a variant member in the Standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[class.union.anom]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union.anon#4)

> A union-like class is a union or a class that has an anonymous union
>   as a direct member. A union-like class `X` has a set of variant
>   members. If `X` is a union, a non-static data member of `X` that is
>   not an anonymous union is a variant member of `X`. **In addition, a
>   non-static data member of an anonymous union that is a member of `X`
>   is also a variant member of `X`**. At most one variant member of a
>   union may have a default member initializer.

English is not my native language, but just by reading this paragraph I have the impression that the highlighted sentence above applies only to the case where `X` is a union, which would turn this definition incomplete, as it would miss the definition of a variant member in a class. So, I must conclude that the highlighted sentence must apply to both cases, unions and classes. Could anyone confirm this? If that is not the case, then I think we a have a defect in this paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the impression that the highlighted sentence above applies only to the case where `X` is a union

The highlighted sentence applies to any union-like class `X` that has an anonymous union member. `X` may be a non-union class.

An example:

```
struct X {      // union-like, non-union class X
    union {     // anonymous union member of X
        int i;  // non-static data member of anonymous union
        float f;
    }
}
```

`i` and `f` are variant members of the union like class `X`, as per the highlighted rule.

Comment: `The highlighted sentence applies to any union-like class X that has an anonymous union member. X may be a non-union class.` That's not what the quote says: "**If x is a union**, a non-static data member of x that is not an anonymous union is ..."

Comment: @WaldB `If x is a union` is a condition for the previous sentence. It no longer applies to the next sentence.

Comment: That was exactly my interpretation, by exclusion. But it's my impression that anyone reading this paragraph would say the contrary, i.e., that the highlighted sentence applies only to the union case. In other words, I think the wording could be improved a little bit here. Don't you agree?

Comment: @WaldB In my opinion, there is no ambiguity, but I suppose further clarification wouldn't hurt. Such as adding an example similar to the one in my answer.